# Search text file for a specific line

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I want to search for specific lines of text in a text file. If the piece of text I am looking for is on a specific line, I would like to read further on that line for more input.

So far I have 3 tags I am looking for.

```
@public
@private
@virtual
```

If I find any of these on a line, I would like to read what comes next so for example I could have a line like this:

```
@public double getHeight();
```

If I determine that the tag I found is `@public` then I have to take the following part after the white-space until I reach the semicolon. The problem is, that I can't really think of an efficient way to do this without excessive use of `charAt(..)` which neither looks pretty but probably isn't good either in the long run for a large file, or for multiple files in a row.

I would like help to solve this efficiently as I currently can't comprehend how I would do it. The code itself is used to parse comments in a C++ file, to later generate a Header file. The Pseudo Code part is where I am stuck. Some people suggest BufferedReader, others say Scanner. I went with Scanner as that seems to be the replacement for BufferedReader.

```
public void run() {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String filename, path;
    StringBuilder puBuilder, prBuilder, viBuilder;
    puBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    prBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    viBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(File f : files) {
        try {
            filename = f.getName();
            path = f.getCanonicalPath();
            scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        String line;
        while((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
            /**
             * Pseudo Code
             * if @public then
             *      puBuilder.append(line.substring(after white space) 
             *      + line.substring(until and including the semicolon);
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scanner is a good replacement if you want to do something other than read a line at a time time. In your case, I suspect being able to read a word at a time would useful i.e. `Scanner.next()` That way the annotation doesn't have to be on the same line as the word after it.

Comment: `charAt`? `indexOf` (for searching `;`) and `substring` are all the String methods that you should need. Also, this is for homework or real world? Because real world parsing is far more complicated than that (what happens in there is a new line after `@virtual`?)

Comment: @SJuan76 This is a hobby project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String tag = "";
if(line.startsWith("@public")){
   tag = "@public";
}else if{....other tags....}

line = line.substring(tag.length(), line.indexOf(";")).trim();
```

This gives you a string that goes from the end of the tag (which in this case is public), and then to the character preceding the semi-colon, and then trims off the whitespace on the ends.

Comment: Correct, substring starts at that "position" in the string. For Example. If we have String s = "cat", cat.substring(1,2) produces "a". http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Comment: But won't this be a problem if the string starts with for example 4 white spaces? Or will white spaces be ignored by `startsWith()`?

Comment: You can use line.trim() first, to eliminate that problem. I.e. line = line.trim(), directly after you read the line.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding you.. but are you just looking for `String.contains()`?

```
if(line.contains("@public")){}
```

Comment: Is it really that simple? When I looked at solutions otherwise, they simply started talking about regex packages.

Comment: @Vipar You could also make use of regex. That will become more handy in your case

Answer (score 1):

```
if (line.startsWith("@public")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are allow to use open source libraries i suggest using the apache common-io and common-lang libraries.  these are widely use java librariues that will make you life a lot more simpler.

```
String text = null;
InputStream in = null;
List<String> lines = null;
for(File f : files) {
    try{
        in = new FileInputStream(f);
        lines = IOUtils.readLines(in);
        for (String line: lines){
            if (line.contains("@public"){
                text = StringUtils.substringBetween("@public", ";");
                ...
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        ...
    }
    finally{
        // alway remember to close the resource 
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
    }
}
```